# Удалить "#" в адресной строке.

Tags: jquery, ajax, location.hash, get

Пытаюсь написать ajax переходы. Вроде бы всё отлично, но адрес создаётся вида:

http://site.ru/#/test

Нельзя ли как-нибудь убрать якорь("#") путём js и оставлять http://site.ru/test?

---

Это мой код, который подгружает контент нужной страницы и создаёт # в адр строке. А вот как его потом удалить?

```
<a href="/test" onclick="nav(this); return false;">перейти</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function nav(a) {
 var url = $(a).attr('href');
 $.get(url, function(data) {
 $('.getc').html($('.getc', data).html());
 location.hash = url;
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: вопрос-ответ?

Comment: @thunder, обновил пост :)

>> Это мой код, который подгружает контент нужной страницы и создаёт # в адр строке. А вот как его потом удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"хочу так же как в вконтакте" =)
ну ладно)

вам нужно использовать history.pushState , в контакте это именно так реализовано, однако оно не поддерживается в "некоторых" браузерах, посему народные умельцы написали давно html5 history api. вот одна из статей на эту тему: [freehabr](http://freehabr.ru/blog/javascript/282.html) ну или на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)

Comment: @thunder, спасибо, набыдлокодил :D

>> location.href = '#'+url; history.replaceState(null, null, url);

Comment: По-моему вконтакте, да и не только в нём, так реализовано, но не для IE. Когда из IE заходишь, то всё через хэш делается, потому IE не знает ничего про pushState, replaceState и т.д.

Comment: @ModaL незачто)
@Kremchik ие не знает, для этого существуют классы дял js, которые в зависимости от браузера используют те или иные функции... в своем скрипте вы будете пользоваться теми же функциями.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'http://site.ru/#/test';
alert(str.replace('#/','')); // = 'http://site.ru/test'
```

Comment: @Deonis, это то понятно :D А как сделать, чтобы он в адресной строке без всяких переходов обновился?

Comment: @ModaLБез перезагрузки, [изменить адресную строку можно](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), а вот изменить её без хэша - не получится.

Answer (score 0):

history.pushState() в помощь, вот на хабре [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/)

Правда, работает только в браузерах, поддерживающих html5, для остальных придется # использовать

Comment: @Owlet, как-нибудь можно определить, поддерживает браузер html5 или нет?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код jquery решает проблему:

```
 $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){
  var anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-100
  }, 1000);
  e.preventDefault();});
```